# Zip folders without parent folder

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, zip

First of all, I've read numerous post on here regarding this topic, but none have helped so far, e.g.

[Zipping without creating parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730477/zipping-without-creating-parent-folder)
[Unix zipping sub directory not including parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174979/unix-zipping-sub-directory-not-including-parent-directory)

Here's what I want. I have the following folder structure:

```
- root
-- subroot
--- subsubroot
---- file1.foo
---- file2.foo
---- file3.foo
---- file4.foo
```

And the result of the zipped file should be, when unzipped

```
file1.foo
file2.foo
file3.foo
file4.foo
```

The crux is that the `file*.foo` are just packages, thus basically being folders itself, so I tried using the `-j` option in conjunction with my recursive option (`-r`), but then I just get a flat hierarchy of all the files.

My current shell command looks like this:

`find root/subroot/subsubroot -name '*.foo' | grep -v somestring | xargs -I % zip -r foos.zip %`

However, the result of that will be exactly like the original structure with all the parent folder.

I don't necessarily have to use the `zip` command, but the resulting file has to be a `zip`.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is nearly correct, although you shouldn't need to use the `-I` option.

**Directory Structure**:

```
.
└── root
    └── subroot
        └── subsubroot
            ├── foo1
            │   └── foo1.pkg
            ├── foo2
            │   └── foo2.pkg
            ├── foo3
            │   └── foo3.pkg
            ├── fooA.pkg
            ├── fooB.pkg
            ├── fooC.pkg
            └── nope.pkg
```

**Command**:

```
find root/subroot/subsubroot -name '*.pkg' | grep -v "nope" | xargs zip -jr foo
```

**Resulting foo.zip**:

```
fooA.pkg
fooB.pkg
fooC.pkg
foo1.pkg
foo2.pkg
foo2.pkg
```

> *There is one caveat.*

If you have this type of directory structure you'll get an error:

```
.
└── root
    └── subroot
        └── subsubroot
            ├── foo1
            │   └── foo1.pkg
            ├── foo2
            │   └── foo2.pkg
            ├── foo3
            │   └── fooC.pkg
            ├── fooA.pkg
            ├── fooB.pkg
            ├── fooC.pkg
            └── nope.pkg
```

**Error**:

```
zip warning:   first full name: root/subroot/subsubroot/foo3/fooC.pkg
               second full name: root/subroot/subsubroot/fooC.pkg
               name in zip file repeated: fooC.pkg
               this may be a result of using -j
```

You'll need to be mindful that files/packages in sub-directories do not have the same filenames otherwise you'll run into problems as shown by `fooC.pkg`. It's assumed this is not the case, since you are attempting to create a flat archive.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that I have tried that as well. And unfortunately I do face the same problem, because each of the packages contain a file with the same name, and the packages are traversed as well – I suppose due to the recursive option. However, I don't actually want it to traverse any further after it has found the `*.pkg` file.

Comment: You could use `maxdepth` with find perhaps. The zip tool should not traverse inside a .pkg file though, as I duplicated the same one and just used a different filename without issue. I’m not sure what type of package you are actually referring to, but if it’s just a directory then that’s likely the issue.

Comment: It's a `dSYM`, so basically just a container. I'll try with `maxdepth`. **EDIT**: `maxdepth` didn't change anything.

Comment: I eventually opted in to just run: `cd root/subroot/subsubroot/ && zip -r outputFile.zip *.dSYM && mv outputFile.zip ../../../ && cd ../../..` Ugly as ever, but at least it works.